# QGIS with c# or vb.net

Tags: qgis, c#, .net, vb.net

Can I add QGIS as a Plugin in .net application and access it using c# or vb.net?
As I can see QGIS plugins are consumed using C++ only.

Comment: QGIS plugins are often written using python language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574801/call-c-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: No, it's not possible. Please read following post: [Is it possible to use DotNet to show a QGIS map?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64479/is-it-possible-to-use-dotnet-to-show-a-qgis-map)