# Embedded QGIS map functionalities in User Interface

Tags: qgis, c++, user-interface, interface

I am using QGIS to analyze a set of data in which there are locations of different interest points and I need to calculate the distance between these locations considering roads network.

I have already done this adding the points as layers and calculating the shortest path with QNEAT3 tool.

Next I want to create a user interface so that user can add points to map, compute the shortest paths and then call an algorithm I have developed in C++.

Which is the best way to embedded QGIS functionalities namely interaction with map in a user interface? Could QGIS be integrated in a user interface made in C++ using Microsoft Foundation Classes?

Comment: see this related question if it helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64479/is-it-possible-to-use-dotnet-to-show-a-qgis-map